# Push notifications with ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, push-notification

I've searched everywhere for this issue, all I found is same problem but with other programming language, so that didn't help me a lot :(

Now I'm using Hibernate, Struts to develop my web site, when an user connect I should display unread messages. I've developed my own solution, but seems to me very costly here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {           
        var url = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>"+"/MessagesRecus.do"; 
        jQuery("#messages").load(url).fadeIn("slow");
    }, 400); //Raffraichir chaque 1 seconde
</script>
```

MessagesRecus.do : is an action that gets unread messages from the DB

I've learned, while I was looking on the other sites, about push notification system.
Does anyone have an idea about it? 
any other suggestion is welcome :)
Thank u in advance.

Comment: When you want to use push notifications with Java have a look at [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html).

Comment: oké thak you, I'm looking at it now :)

Comment: Hi again, could u please give me an example of how to do a simple notif with this DWR, if u have it, thanx.

Comment: You can begin [here](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/reverse-ajax/index.html).

Comment: Hi, apparently what I wanted to do is not push notifs, but polling notifs, to be clear I want the server to sent me notif when new message's received, with any request from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you a specific system. But currently the best solution I think is to use HTML5 websockets. But there are also javascript libraries that support "Ajax Push" or "Comet", like for example JQuery. I think that should point you on the right track.

Comment: Hi, could you please give some more details about how to use websockets with js, 'cuz I'm really newbie in this world.
If u have examples that would be cool, knowing that I'm using : Struts2, Hibernate and JSP.
Thank u again :)

Comment: I used Ajax Push/Comet in the past but never had the time/project to actually try out Websockets. I googled a little an I think this might be good start, from which you can adapt it to your application.
http://ajeeshwrites.blogspot.de/2011/02/peek-at-websockets.html
It's two years old, so the remark on browser compatibility shouldn't be true any more and I think nearly all browsers support it by now.
Good luck.